# How do I import a LESS stylesheet depending on the variable?

Tags: less

```
@template-productlist-id = 1;

   & when (@template-productlist-id = 0) {
      import "product-lists/product-list0.less";
   }

   & when (@template-productlist-id > 0) {
      import "product-lists/product-list.less";
   }
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Still importing 2 files. How can I achieve that?

Comment: This code looks suspect to me. What are you expecting to happen? Do you understand that LESS is compiled to CSS so if you want to change the @template-productlist-id value you will have to do it server side and then re-serve the compiled CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you code is not valid Less, try:

1. you should assign variables with a colon (`:`)
2. your import statement should start with a at (`@`)

.

```
@template-productlist-id: 0;
.import() {
   & when (@template-productlist-id = 0) {
      @import "product-lists/product-list0.less";
   }

   & when (@template-productlist-id > 0) {
      @import "product-lists/product-list.less";
   }
}
.import();
```

Or indeed also the following Less code will give the expected result:

```
   @template-productlist-id: 0;
   & when (@template-productlist-id = 0) {
      @import "product-lists/product-list0.less";
   }

   & when (@template-productlist-id > 0) {
      @import "product-lists/product-list.less";
   }
```